# Redirect to error controller in case of any type of exception?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a Spring Boot application. I have created a simple demo method to showcase my issue.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        int i=0;
        if(i==0){
        throw new RuntimeException("test exception");
        }
        return (List<Customer>) jdbcCustomerDAO.findAll();
    }
```

Here i am throwing a `RuntimeException`. I want to redirect it to `ErrorController` from where I want it to open `error.jsp` inside /src/main/webapp.

```
@Controller
public class MyCustomErrorController implements ErrorController{

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

     @GetMapping("/error")
     public ModelAndView handleError(Model model) {
         model.addAttribute("message", "Oops Sorry !!!!");
         return new ModelAndView("error");             
     }
    }
```

`Error.jsp file`

```
${message}
```

I am getting this error on page:

```
This page isn’t working
localhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

How can I redirect it to my error pagE?

Answer (score 3):

Why not capture the exceptions using Spring own feature regarding errors? You can use something called `ControllerAdvice` (documented [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html)). So, in your case, you can do something similar to the following:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyCustomErrorController {

 @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
 public ModelAndView handleError(RuntimeException exception) {
     model.addAttribute("message", "Oops Sorry !!!!");
     return new ModelAndView("error");
 }

}
```

It might be that you can use this type of error handling instead. Let me know if something does not work as intended. A small reference can also be found on Spring' own [blog](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc).